# Como retornar HTML no Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, react

Tenho um código que é um botão, este botão tem que ficar oculto caso uma variável booleana esteja em falso, logo, a minha ideia do código seria algo assim :

```
<div className="row">
   {RHPerm === true ? {
       return <div>
                 <label>Button Label</label>
                 <button>Button content</button>
              </div>
   } : {
        return <> </>
   }}
</div>
```

Meu pensamento seria que algo assim desse certo, mas o código não aceita essa lógica HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maneira mais simples é verificando se a variável está como o valor `true`, mostra o trecho do código, ***exemplo***:

```js
function App() {
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={status} onChange={e => setStatus(!status) } /> {status ? "Esconder" : "Mostrar"}
      </div>
      {status && (
      <div>
           <label>Button Label</label>
           <button>Button content</button>
      </div> )}
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

ou seja, `{status &&` se o primeiro valor for verdadeiro mostre o contéudo.

Comment: mais um voto útil, e só aumenta!